# Why is everything blue?

Tags: windows, colors

Okay, I think a screen shot can best explain this. It happens on everything. Seemly toolbars in any application really.

Mostly Microsoft ;).

[image]

any solutions on how to fix this would be great.

Its been like this for months, and im finally fed up with it.

Comment: In the future, try to come up with better categories for your questions than "bug". It's to your own advantage.

Comment: @Joel I didnt know what category to put it in :S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start Menu then type Personalization and click it. From that window click Window Color then click Advanced appearance settings.

From there choose Selected Items in the drop-down box and choose a nicer Color1 and also set the Color below from white to something that has contrast.

Updated: Alternatively just click the Windows 7 Aero theme from the Personalization window to reset all the theme colors and options.

Comment: You sir, are a genius. *scratches head*, how did it ever get changed to blue  :/ , By any chance, you know how to set the default again, or what the default is?

Comment: Roommate? Friend? Co-worker? Family member? :)